# Understanding the lib keyword

Tags: class-method, ffl, anura

Is `lib` a special keyword for Frogatto Formula Language (FFL)? That seems to be the way of invoking class methods.  For example:

```
where frog = lib.citadel.create_creature('Giant Frog')
```

Also, I am interested to know where can I find a list of all the available `lib.****` library objects and how to list of all their available functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a keyword as such, more a symbol that appears in the standard namespace. As such it is functionally fairly close to a keyword.

When you create a class by adding a file e.g. `data/classes/blah.cfg` then a singleton instance of this class will be available using `lib.blah`. This is a convenient way of effectively creating your own namespace of functions -- create a class, add functions to it, then your functions can be accessed using `lib.classname.functionname()`

Comment: Interesting... although, I'm not sure I would call it a singleton if you can still have more instances